# How to read context parameter with docbase Root from server.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jdbc

When I try to access the data-source through server.xml and with docbase set to my application. It works perfect. But if I try to access the same through docBase=root and path="" , it is not getting accessed. I'm using Tomcat

```
    <Context docBase="Configurator" path="/configurator" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Configurator">
      <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" maxActive="10" maxIdle="4" name="jdbc/DB" password="xyz" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xx.xx.xx:1433;DatabaseName=23" username="sa"/>
    </Context>


  <Context path="" docBase="ROOT" reloadable="true" crossContext="true" override="true">
   <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" maxActive="10" maxIdle="4" name="jdbc/Db2" password="xyz@123" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xx.xx.xx:1433;DatabaseName=Real23" username="sa"/>
</Context>
```

This second value "Db2" I'm not able to access through below code -

```
try {
    Context initContext;
    initContext = new InitialContext();
    DataSource o = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/Db2");
    System.out.println(o.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can anyone please suggest what should I do to access such elements from server.xml where docbase is root in tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not totally sure what you are trying to do.  There are 2 possibilities:

1. You are trying to deploy a JNDI resource under the root war.
2. You are trying to deploy a JNDI resource globally to all web application contexts.

If the former, then this is never going to work by design.  The fact that a context is the root context makes the hierarchical URL structure seem relevant, but it's not.  The root webapp is just like another other web app.  Therefore, the rules about class loader and resource isolation apply.  The root context / web app is not in any way "above" other contexts / web apps, so sharing resources that way is not allowed.

If you are trying to make the resource global to all apps, then don't put it under a context, but make it global in Tomcat.  Tomcat has a global `context.xml` which is merged into each web app in memory at runtime.  I think you can also put it directly in `server.xml` under `<GlobalNamingResources>`.  See the Tomcat documentation here for details: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html

Comment: Thanks! I fall in #2 of the possibilities and your explanation helped greatly.